# UITableView excessively refreshing without command

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view within a UIViewController to display calendar information in table format. It displays the information with one row dedicated to a date then all events on that day underneath it and so forth. I added a mapper array of ints so i know at what row index each date is at so i can add special formatting to that cell. On the first load, it will load appropriately and correctly, but soon as i begin moving up and down the view, the format doesn't stay and incorrect cells get the special formatting, this only happens to cells outside my view. Im not sure why this happening, but i'm fairly certain it is related to excessive refreshing.

```
import UIKit

class CalendarController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()
    var info: [newsarticle] = []
    var postTitle: String = String()
    var postDesc: String = String()
    var eName: String = String()
    var index: Int = Int()
    var organizedinfo: [String] = [String]()
    var headDates: String = String()
    var mapper: [Int]  = [Int]()
    var datemapper: [Int] = [Int]()
    var colorcatch = 0
    /*
     // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
     // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
     override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
     // Drawing code
     }
     */
    @IBOutlet var multiview: UITableView!

    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://brrsd.k12.nj.us/rss/Calendar.xml")!
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        orgData()
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WebpageController.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        multiview.addSubview(refreshControl)

    }
    func returnDate(numb: String) -> String
    {
     let fullString = numb
    let dates = fullString.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map(String.init)
      if(dates.count == 3)
      {
        return dates[2]
        }
        else{
            return dates[1]
        }

    }
    func orgData(){
        var i = 0
        while i < info.count{
            if(returnDate(info[i].title) == headDates)
            {
                mapper.append(organizedinfo.count)
                organizedinfo.append("*" + cleanTitle(info[i]))
            }
            else{
                datemapper.append(organizedinfo.count)
                organizedinfo.append("[" + returnDate(info[i].title).substringFromIndex(info[i].title.startIndex) + "]")
                mapper.append(organizedinfo.count)
                organizedinfo.append("*" + cleanTitle(info[i]))
                headDates = returnDate(info[i].title)
            }
            i += 1
        }
    }
    func cleanTitle(a: newsarticle) -> String{
        let fullString = a.title
         let dates = fullString.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map(String.init)
        if(dates.count == 2){
        return dates[0]
        }
        else{
            return dates[0] + dates[1]
        }
    }
    func refresh(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        colorcatch = 0
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://brrsd.k12.nj.us/rss/Calendar.xml")!
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        multiview.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qualifiedName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        eName = elementName
        if elementName == "item" {
            postTitle = String()
            postDesc = String()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return organizedinfo.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell
        if let reusedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") {
            cell = reusedCell
        } else {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        if let label = cell.textLabel {
            label.text = organizedinfo[indexPath.row]
        }
        if(colorcatch < datemapper.count){
        for element in datemapper{
            if element == indexPath.row
            {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
        }
            colorcatch += 1
        }
        return cell    }


    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if eName == "title" {
                postTitle += data
            } else if eName == "description" {
                postDesc += data
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            let newsart: newsarticle = newsarticle()
            newsart.title = postTitle
            newsart.description = postDesc
            info.append(newsart)
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        index = indexPath.row
        var a = true
        for element in datemapper{
            if element == index
            {
                a = false
            }
        }
        if a{
        performSegueWithIdentifier("CalendarTransfer", sender:self)
        }
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let Destination: FullCalendar = segue.destinationViewController as! FullCalendar
        var i = 0
        while mapper[i] != index{
            i += 1
        }
        Destination.info = info[i]


    }



    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

}
```

Comment: For loops in cellForRowAtIndexPath are a bad idea and you need to set the colours appropriately in the case where there isn't a match as cells are reused. You could use an NSMutableIndexSet to store your date rows rather than array and avoid the for loop

Comment: This is an annoying aspect of `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` and `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Note that when you scroll to a new cell in a table view, you are reusing a cell that that has already been made, and in your case formatted. If you don't "unformat" some of the customization you made on the cell that is being reused it will unexpectedly appear in the new *cellForRowAtIndexPath*.